# Remove subslists that contains a set of words in Nested List on R

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list videos inside the sublist there is element "title" I want to filter and remove all the sublists in which x$title has the words like {trailer, highlights, match}. Can some good soul help me in solving this ?

[Here is the Nested List in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2seNE.png)

[Here is the Sublist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AIp5.png)

(Sorry for my language) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Find all the sublists `x` for which `x$title` contains any of the forbidden words and remove them.

```
forbidden <- c("trailer", "highlights", "match")
bad <- sapply(videos, function(x) any(stringr::str_detect(x$title, regex(forbidden, ignore_case = T))))
videos <- videos[-which(bad)]
```

Comment: I tried this 
videos <- videos[!sapply(videos, function(x) any(stringr::str_detect(x$title, forbidden)))]

from what you suggested and it worked but it is case sensative how can I opt for no case sensative ?

Comment: So I got it like this

videos <- videos[!sapply(videos, function(x) any(stringr::str_detect(x$title, regex((forbidden),ignore_case = TRUE))))]

Comment: Yes, I found it too. I am updating my response.

Answer (score 0):

Making a small sample dataset (See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

```
l <- list(
  list(id = "a", title = "blabla trailer"),
  list(id = "b", title = "keep this one"),
  list(id = "c", title = "remove this match"))
```

To subset list elements based on search patterns we can use some regular expression to find matches those matches. We can use `|` to search for multiple possibilities.

```
# base R
l[!sapply(l, function(x){grepl("match|highlight|trailer", x$title)})]
# purrr
library(purrr)
l[!map_lgl(l, ~ grepl("match|highlight|trailer", .x$title))]

[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "b"

[[1]]$title
[1] "keep this one"
```